# Required not working in my form with easyAdmin

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I've got in my EasyAdmin a CollectionField which have in setEntryType my ExtraType => `->setEntryType(ExtraType::class)`.
In my ExtraType, I choose 2 fields on 3 to get the required true and the last in false but the required doesn't work :

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('isVisible', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Visible',
            ])
            ->add('createdAt', DateTimeType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'label' => 'Date',
                'required' => true
            ])

        ;
    }
```

I don't know why the required does not appear in the dom

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, to get the required this is how I did :
`'attr' => ['required' => true]`

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with a similar problem this is my solution:
Use `->setRequired(true)` on the Field that uses this form type, then add `'required' => false` to any field you do not want to be required.

For some reason EasyAdmin seems to only consider the `'required'` attribute set in buildForm() when using `->setRequired(true)`. Without this setting, or even when using `->setRequired(false)`, EasyAdmin appears to ignore it. With this solution you can still achieve the desired result, at least I did.